# rails 3.2 couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.core'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting the following errors when using DataTables gem on heroku production.

```
couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.core'
couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.theme'
```

I followed the approach given at http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables?view=asciicast
Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: please show us your gemfile, your js manifest file etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*jquery-datatables-rails* gem does not install jQuery UI gem. At least their .gemspec says so. So, you need to add the gem manually in your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

[Github](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails) page infact recommends to add in assets group

```
group :assets do
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end
```

If you do not use bundler, you just install the gem using following command:

```
gem install jquery-ui-rails
```

Comment: Thanks i had jquery-ui-rails gem also in the Gemfile. Putting the gem declaration outside of the assets group worked. I think this is specific to heroku.

Comment: nice to know it worked and thanks for letting us know the hack for heroku :).

Answer (score 4):

I changed the Gemfile with the server running. Restart the server solved this problem.